# ASP.NET Core Web API - Measuring response data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have an ASP.NET Core Web API project. Today on accident I found an API method that was returning unnecessary amounts of data.

In my example we were returning users along with countries which is what we needed, but we were also returning a list of cities for each country so that was a tremendous amount if data, I was able to reduce it from 7MB to 23KB (per Insomnia client).

I was able to fix this by performing a select and creating a new country object and not passing in the cities property. I am not even sure if that's the right way to fix that problem but I will leave that for another time. My question is...

Is there a tool/nuget package out there that would provide this type of info? I'd like to get an idea on how much data we are sending to the clients when different methods are called. We have app insights but I don't believe it provides that data or at least I don't see it.

Thank you!

Comment: Writing a custom middleware for measuring could be an option.

Comment: Yeah that's the route (no pun intended) that I might have to take if there isn't something that exists.

Comment: This question would have been down-voted by members, if it was asked by a member with 500 of reputation or less.

Comment: @Benjamin why is that? I've had this account for a couple years now, never really paid attention to the points, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by writing some middleware code that logs the results to azure application insights, here is a copy of the code if anyone needs it:

https://gist.github.com/tekguy/52b245f6582158d7240f80bf46c4cc71

You can then query this info by using app insights log query:

requests
| order by timestamp desc 
| project url, customMeasurements.Size